# Quartz 2.1.5: Trying to create a job detail dynamically using JobBuilder

Tags: java, classloader, quartz-scheduler

I've seen several posts about this, however don't work with the new JobBuilder approach in Quartz.

I'm trying to create a JobDetail dynamically, using a string that stores the class name. However I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
 The method newJob(Class<? extends Job>) in the type JobBuilder is not applicable 
 for the arguments (Class<capture#6-of ?>)
```

This is the code:

```
String s = "ClassName";
Class<?> jobClass = null;
try {
    jobClass = Class.forName (s);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new MsgException ( "Requested Job Class not found" );
}

JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(jobClass).
        withIdentity(jobKey).
        withDescription(description).
        storeDurably().
        usingJobData(dataMap).
        build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the error message? `newJob` takes a parameter of type `Class<? extends Job>`, but you're passing it a parameter of type `Class<?>`. As a quick fix, you can try changing it to

```
newJob((Class<? extends Job>)jobClass)
```

In the long run you'll probably want to do actual checking to make sure it is a subclass of Job, since otherwise you'll get mysterious runtime errors from inside Quartz when it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the newJob constructor expects a compile time reference while methods such as Class.forName() are run time references.  An intermediate solution is to use something like:

```
private void makeNewJob(Class<? extends Job> jobClass, String identity,
    String environment)
{
    JobDetail job = newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(identity, environment)
        .build();

// additional code
}
```

and call with:

```
makeNewJob(MyJob.class, "MyJob", "Production");
```